# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters' When running Google Sheets API Setup

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-requests, google-sheets-api

I am following the [setup guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) for Google Sheets API and I have followed step 1 and installed the necessary libraries.

When I try to run the code in step 2 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ben/Desktop/Current & Upcomming Work/_Active Code/AllTheatreJobs/quickstart.py", line 4, in <module>
  from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
File "C:\Users\ben\Desktop\Current & Upcomming Work\_Active Code\AllTheatreJobs\venv\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  from .interactive import get_user_credentials
File "C:\Users\ben\Desktop\Current & Upcomming Work\_Active Code\AllTheatreJobs\venv\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\interactive.py", line 24, in <module>
  import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
File "C:\Users\ben\Desktop\Current & Upcomming Work\_Active Code\AllTheatreJobs\venv\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 68, in <module>
  import google.auth.transport.requests
File "C:\Users\ben\Desktop\Current & Upcomming Work\_Active Code\AllTheatreJobs\venv\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 37, in <module>
  import requests.adapters  # pylint: disable=ungrouped-imports
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters'
```

I've have installed the **requests library** but that does not solve the issue. I can't see any other reports of this issue anywhere else. Any advice?

Comment: Could you run `pip show requests` and show the output?

Comment: @Bonfire Have uninstalled and then reinstalled requests and it's working now. I guess it just hadn't installed cleanly or something first time round.

Comment: Perhaps you had used the wrong command for installing it in the first place. There is confusion between `pip`/`pip3` etc

Comment: I'm using a venv with Pycharm, so that sort of issue should be avoided automatically by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the requests library and then re-installed it, which solved the issue.

Comment: Yep same issue. Pycharm + venv. Reinstalling my virtualenv fixed the issue.